# Why is there only one integration in the solution if there is two integral in the formula?

Tags: autocorrelation, random-process, random, complex-random-variable

In this problem the random variable is theta and according to the formula there should be two integrations but in the solution there is only one . Nor am i able to understand the meaning of x1 and x2 in the formula. this problem is driving me nuts..
[image: in this problem the random variable is theta]
[image: this is the solution]
[image: here is the formula]

Answer (score 1):

You have a single random variable $\Theta$ in this example, so taking the expectation with respect to that random variable results in a single integral. The formula for $R_X(\tau)$ in your question is rather messy and full of mistakes; it should be as follows:

$$\begin{align}R_X(\tau)&=E[X(t+\tau)X(t)]\\&=E[a\sin(\omega_0t+\omega_0\tau+\Theta)\cdot a\sin(\omega_0t+\Theta)]\\&=\frac{a^2}{2}E[\cos(\omega_0\tau)-\cos(2\omega_0t+\omega_0\tau+2\Theta)]\\&=\frac{a^2}{2}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}[\cos(\omega_0\tau)-\cos(2\omega_0t+\omega_0\tau+2\Theta)]d\Theta\\&=\frac{a^2}{2}\cos(\omega_0\tau)\end{align}$$

Comment: What would be the formula then ..if there is only one random variable in the autocorrelation function...??

Comment: @VishalPoddar: It's not about autocorrelation, it's about how to evaluate the expectation operator: $E[g(\theta,\ldots)]=\int p(\theta)g(\theta,\ldots)d\theta$, where $\ldots$ stands for other variables that the function $g(\cdot)$ may depend on, as long as they're not random. The variable $\theta$ is the (only) random variable here, so you have to integrate over $g(\cdot)$ multiplied by the PDF $p(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the definition of the random process as :

$$ X(t) = a \sin(\omega_0 t + \Theta) \tag{1} $$

where $a$ and $\omega_0$ are deterministic constants and $\Theta$ is a continuous R.V. uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi]$.

According to the indexed-set of RV interpretation of a R.P., for each index $t$ you have a new R.V denoted as $X_t$ which has its own density function $f_{X_t}(x)$ for each $t$. Then the following expectation is actually looking for

$$ E\{ X(t) \} = \int x f_{X_t}(x) dx \tag{2} $$

However, based on a well known relation in probability theory, the following helps. If a RV $Y$ is a function of another RV $X$, such as given by $Y = g(X)$, then the following expectations are equivalent:

$$ E\{ Y \} = \int y f_Y(y) dy \tag{3}$$
$$ E\{ g(X) \} = \int g(x) f_X(x) dx \tag{4}$$

Now if you look at the indexed RV $X_t$ of the R.P. $X(t)$ you can see that it's a function of the R.V. $\Theta$ :

$$X_t = g(\Theta) = a \sin( \omega_0 t + \Theta) $$

Hence the Expectation in Eq.2 can be computed based on the reasoning of Eq.4 as

$$ E\{ X(t) \} = E\{ g(\Theta) \}  = \int g(\theta) f_{\Theta}(\theta) d\theta \tag{5} $$

$$ E\{ X(t) \} = \int a \sin(\omega_0 t + \theta) f_{\Theta}(\theta) d\theta \tag{6} $$

A very similar reasoning shows that the expectation of the product $X(t+\tau) X(t)$ can be computed by treating the product as a function of the RV $\Theta$, instead of using the joint PDF of the RVs $X_{t}$ and $X_{t+\tau}$ as:

$$ X(t+\tau) X(t) = h( \Theta) \tag{7} $$

where $h(\cdot)$ is given by:

$$ h(\theta) = a^2 \sin(\omega_0 (t+\tau) + \theta) \sin(\omega_0 t + \theta) \tag{8}$$

Then the expectation will be evaluated as

$$ E\{ X(t+\tau) X(t) \} = E\{ h(\Theta) \} = \int h(\theta) f_{\Theta} (\theta) d\theta \tag{9} $$

$$ E\{ X(t+\tau) X(t) \} = \int a^2 \sin(\omega_0 (t+\tau) + \theta) \sin(\omega_0 t + \theta)  f_{\Theta} (\theta) d\theta \tag{10} $$